# In which levels are each treasure?

Tags: uncharted-fortune-hunter

I'm trying to find the treasures in *Uncharted: Fortune Hunter*.

So far I've found treasures in the following puzzles (I'm still in progressing in the game):

1. Captain Kidd's Boa Mask: puzzles 5, 7, 13, 16, 19, 21, 25, 26 (complete);
2. Macalpin's Viking Sword: puzzles 9, 10.
3. Grace O'Malley's Celtic Brooch: puzzles ...
4. Pizarro's Skull Mug: puzzles ...
5. King Toera's Golden Tortoise: puzzles ...
6. John Hawkins' Funeral Urn: puzzles ...

In which puzzles are the other treasures?

Comment: Why the downvote? I tried to follow all the rules when posting here. Did I do anything wrong? The research effort is that I played the game and looked on the Internet but at the time of posting there was nothing in relation to the second map and beyond.

Comment: I downvoted, and there are several reasons, so I'll list them all. Firstly, you were very unclear on what you were asking. You appear to have downvoted a question for making the same interpretation, only to copy the contents into your own wiki answer. You have since clarified, but in trying to help your question, I have ran into two other issues.

Comment: You will find a treasure on levels 15 and 19. I found that out with a two minute google search, and from what I can see, the site was updated with that information before you posted. So a downvote for lack of research effort.

Comment: @Timelord64 In map 2 and above, the treasures are hidden in walls or behind traps that are not needed to complete the puzzle... Hence the question, actually. Also, the answer I provided I put it in a separate answer that I put as a community wiki (so I get no rep on the back of other users), because the 2 answers I got were incomplete in regards to the question. Also if the question is bad, you can edit it, which you did... only to remove a tag (I'm not saying you weren't right to do so, just that you edited it but not on the actual content).

Comment: Finally, I don't know what you searched for but I couldn't find the answers for levels 15 & 19 by myself. If I had found, I wouldn't have asked the question. I had no idea that 9 and 10 were the first, I could simply have missed several treasures before those puzzles. It happens that I did not, but IMO, it's merely a coincidence. And I'll add that my community answer is more complete than the two answers previously given since it indicates level 2 for map 3. So, no, there is no malice from me.

Comment: I googled "uncharted: fortune hunter guide" and went for the first link with "Walkthrough" in its name..

Comment: @Timelord64 Hmmm... I reread your comment. No I didn't downvote any answer. I'd be one lower rep than I was 2 days ago. The only rep I lost was due to your admitted downvote on this question. I don't know how I can prove it, but I didn't downvote. The answer was useful, yes but incomplete. So IMO, it didn't deserve nor a +1 nor a -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The treasures are located in the following puzzles:

1. **Captain Kidd's Boa Mask**, 8 treasures: puzzles 5, 7, 13, 16, 19, 21, 25, 26.
2. **Macalpin's Viking Sword**, 12 treasures: puzzles 9, 10, 15, 19, 21, 22, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 39.
3. **Grace O'Malley's Celtic Brooch**, 4 treasures: puzzles 2, 8, 12, 17
4. **Pizarro's Skull Mug**, 8 treasures: puzzles 3, 7, 9, 17, 29, 31, 32, 37
5. **King Toera's Golden Tortoise**, 8 treasures: puzzles 1, 7, 15, 17, 18, 20, 25, 26.
6. **John Hawkins' Funeral Urn**, X treasures: puzzles ... -not yet available-

Answer (score 0):

The treasure in level 22 appears to be the one you are missing.

Malcapin's then ends up being: 9, 10, 15, 19, 21, 22, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, and 39.

Answer (score 0):

King Toera's Golden Tortoise: 1,7,15,17,18,20,25,26